# GYRO JQuery in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, datatables.js

I'm trying to use Jquery from below link in my aura component. I wanted the search and multi select functionality from that table. Can some one please guide me how to use that Jquery library in aura with sample code.

https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I have tried this one https://datatables.net/ and able to use the Jqeury, but for Gyro, I'm not understanding how to start with passing the data.

Here is the code which I tried.

```
   Datatable.cmp
<aura:component controller="jQueryDataTableCtrl">
    <ltng:require styles="{! $Resource. datatable + '/DataTables-1.10.16/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'}" 
                  scripts="{!join(',', 
                           $Resource.jquery224 , 
                           $Resource.datatable + '/DataTables-1.10.16/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')
                           }" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>  
    
    <aura:attribute name="lstOpp" type="opportunity[]"/>     
    
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <table id="tableId" class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Stage</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Close Date</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOpp}" var="acc">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!acc.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!acc.Type}</td>
                        <td>{!acc.StageName}</td>
                        <td>{!acc.Amount}</td>
                        <td>{!acc.CloseDate}</td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
   
    doInit : function(component,event,helper){
        var action = component.get('c.fetchOpportunity');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //set response value in lstOpp attribute on component.
                component.set('v.lstOpp', response.getReturnValue());
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#tableId').DataTable();
                    // add lightning class to search filter field with some bottom margin..  
                    $('div.dataTables_filter input').addClass('slds-input');
                    $('div.dataTables_filter input').css("marginBottom", "10px");
                }, 500);          
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

APEX:

```
public with sharing class jQueryDataTableCtrl {
@AuraEnabled
   public static list <Opportunity> fetchOpportunity() {
      Return [SELECT Name,Type,StageName,Amount,CloseDate FROM Opportunity LIMIT 30];
          
    }
}
```

but, in GYRO , i'm trying to understand how to pass the data and will that work in salesforce?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Could you explain where you got stuck? This question may be closed if it does not have MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : I have tired to look for using Jquery in aura , but I'm not understanding where to start for this. I will post code for other datatable which I tried.

Comment: Have you checked the docs here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the GYRO is just an extension to `datatable` you will just have to add that as a Datatable params like this:

```
({

    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {

    },

    scriptsLoaded: function (component, event, helper) {
        const action = component.get('c.fetchOpportunity');
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {

            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //set response value in lstOpp attribute on component.
                component.set('v.lstOpp', response.getReturnValue());
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#tableId').DataTable({
                            'columnDefs': [
                                { 'targets': 0, 'checkboxes': true }
                            ]
                        }
                    );
                    // add lightning class to search filter field with some bottom margin..
                    $('div.dataTables_filter input').addClass('slds-input');
                    $('div.dataTables_filter input').css("marginBottom", "10px");
                }, 500);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

And you component will have an extra `th` and `td` param so that you have space for your checkbox

```
<ltng:require styles="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.FrameworkBase_CF + '/css/datatables.min.css',
                       $Resource.FrameworkBase_CF + '/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css')
                       }"
              scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.FrameworkBase_CF + '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
                       $Resource.FrameworkBase_CF + '/js/datatables.min.js',
                       $Resource.FrameworkBase_CF + '/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js')
                       }" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="lstOpp" type="opportunity[]"/>

<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
    <table id="tableId" class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Stage</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Close Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOpp}" var="acc">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{!acc.Name}</td>
                <td>{!acc.Type}</td>
                <td>{!acc.StageName}</td>
                <td>{!acc.Amount}</td>
                <td>{!acc.CloseDate}</td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Also I would say its better to do your `enqueueaction` in `scriptsLoaded` method, so that you are sure that only after the scripts are laoded you are initilizing the datatable not before. It can throw uncaught exceptions sometime if you do that in `doInit`, or just enqueue action in your doInit but do datatable initilization in `scriptsLoaded`.

Also for a smooth experience show a spinner and hide the table from UI with some class and hide the spinner and remove the hidden class when the datatable is finally initialized.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one quick question, is your static resource (FrameworkBase_CF) downloaded from GYRO , as I see extra files added? where can I find them?

Comment: That's same as yours, only extra files are `dataTables.checkboxes.min.js` and `dataTables.checkboxes.css` which are downloaded from  GYRO

Comment: Thank you very much, I owe you, I have been trying for a while on this. One more follow up . Sorry for too many questions. I'm trying to fetch the data of selected rows, if you have time can you help me how to call that method in JS to get the data

Comment: Please post a new question for this as this question.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327588/gyro-datatable-js-in-aura-component-trying-to-fetch-selected-values-of-the-tabl . posted here, can you please check.

Comment: Updated the answer.